# Determing equivalence of categories by looking at images of functors in $\mathrm{Set}$.

Tags: category-theory

The motivation for this question is that I'm trying to figure out ways of using a fixed category (like $\mathrm{Set}$ or $\mathrm{Top}$) to answer things about other categories.

Suppose I have two not-necessarily-distinct categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$.

$\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{D}$ if and only if there exists a functor $\mathbf{F}:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ such that $\mathbf{F}$ is full, faithful, and essentially surjective.

$\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are isomorphic if and only if they are isomorphic as objects in the category of categories.

I'm wondering whether we can detect equivalence of categories by looking at images of functors in $\mathrm{Set}$ *that are constrained to identify isomorphic objects*.

Let $\mathbf{G}_I$ be an indexed family of all functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathrm{Set}$ where the image of $\mathbf{G}_i(\mathcal{C})$ is a skeletal category. Let the collection of all images be denoted by $\mathbf{G}_I(\mathcal{C})$. Let $\mathbf{H}_I(\mathcal{D})$ be defined analogously.

Let's say that $\mathbf{G}_I(\mathcal{C})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{H}_I(\mathcal{D})$ is every category on the left is isomorphic to at least one category on the right and every category on the right is isomorphic to at least one category on the left.

Is it true that

$$ \mathcal{C} \; \text{is equivalent to} \; \mathcal{D} \iff \mathbf{G}_I(\mathcal{C}) \; \text{is isomorphic to} \; \mathbf{H}_I(\mathcal{D}) $$

The $\implies$ direction is straightforward *intuitively*. By the conditions I imposed in my definition, each functor must necessarily send isomorphic objects in $\mathcal{C}$ to the same object in $\mathrm{Set}$ and likewise for $\mathcal{D}$.

I'm wondering about $\Longleftarrow$, however. I'm not sure whether a somewhat bizarre collection of subcategories of $\mathrm{Set}$ is rich enough to distinguish any pair of non-equivalent categories.

Comment: What is $I$? And does it vary? What does it mean that a collection of images is isomorphic to a different collection? (In any case, the answer to your question is "no", since your construction obviously forgets too much structure. Honestly, I do not really understand the whole idea behind it.)

Comment: $I$ is some indices, organized into some kind of class or collection that's big enough to hold all the functors going to $\mathrm{Set}$ with the relevant property. Okay, so it doesn't work. How coarse is the relation defined here? Also, I made a mistake applying $\mathrm{obj}$ everywhere. I am looking at the images of the various functors applied to $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ as categories (subcategories of $\mathrm{Set}$), not as collections of objects.

Comment: A collection of images is isomorphic to another collection of images if each category that appears on the left is isomorphic to at least one category on the right and vice versa.

Comment: Ok so you do not need indices at all. Is your question the following? "If $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ are categories such that for every functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ whose image is skeletal there is some functor $G : \mathcal{D} \to \mathbf{Set}$ whose image is skeletal such that $F(\mathcal{C}) \cong G(\mathcal{D})$, and vice versa, then $\mathcal{C} \simeq \mathcal{D}$."

Comment: Yes, that's my question. If the answer is `no`, I'm also curious how coarse that relation is.